# How to get each element of a Rails list into select_tag in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails list like this :

```
["Ananda College", "Nalanda College"]
```

It is taken from a database. I have selected one column and taken all its entries. Now I need to put this list into a select tag! Select each one from the select box. How can I do this?

I tried to add a each do block inside the select_tag and it didn't work.

PS : The list is dynamically generated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use the form helper `options_for_select` which takes an array.

A common way of doing this is setting an array in the **controller**:

```
@colleges = College.uniq.pluck(:name)
```

Then in your **view**:

```
<%= f.select :college, options_for_select(@college) %>
```

Take a look at the docs for [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) for more implementation details.

Comment: Actually the list is dynamically generated :) It will change according to what they select in other select boxes...

Comment: Machan, replace the array with `College.all.map(&:name).sort`, I think you have a column name called ':name'

Comment: @sameera207 No machan, the database contain the school, address, provice, district and some other details. I selected only the school names and took it to a list. I need the select box to show only the school names :D

Comment: options_for_select takes an `Array`, whether that is hard typed or dynamically generated is irrelevant. Again, I would encourage you to familiarize yourself with the `select_tag`, `options_for_select`, and `collection_select` form builder methods.

Answer (score 1):

try this it might be helpful

```
<%= f.collection_select :college_id, Collage.all, :id,:Name %>
```